# Last accessed timestamp of a Netezza table?

Tags: netezza

Does anyone know of a query that gives me details on the last time a Netezza table was accessed for any of the operations (select, insert or update) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a [history database](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_nzhistcreatedb_cmd.html) (using `nzhistcreatedb`) which acts as a detailed access log and then consult [the views and tables](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_qhist_views_tbls.html) that it provides (e.g. `$v_hist_table_access_stats`).

If you haven't already got this in place then I'm not aware of any way to find out who accessed a table unless you trawl through the logs in `/nz/kit/log/postgres/`.

Answer (score 0):

it would be...

```
SELECT FORMAT_TABLE_ACCESS(usage),
   hq.submittime
FROM "$v_hist_queries" hq
   INNER JOIN "$hist_table_access_3" hta
USING (NPSID, NPSINSTANCEID, OPID, SESSIONID)
WHERE hq.dbname    = 'URBN_TARGET'
AND hta.tablename  = 'CUSTOMER_ORDER_RANK'
AND hq.SUBMITTIME  > '01-01-2015'
AND hq.SUBMITTIME <= CURRENT_DATE
AND
   (
      instr(FORMAT_TABLE_ACCESS(usage),'ins') > 0
   OR instr(FORMAT_TABLE_ACCESS(usage),'upd') > 0
   OR instr(FORMAT_TABLE_ACCESS(usage),'del') > 0
   OR instr(FORMAT_TABLE_ACCESS(usage),'read') > 0
   )
AND status=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt as well. To check what is the last connexion per user per database

Put every database name on a file called db.txt
Go into the log directory as said previously (/nz/kit/log/postgres) and then run this script :

```
#!/bin/ksh
for database in `cat db.txt`

do

echo "Base $database :"

cat pg.log*|grep ${database}|grep connection|grep user|awk ' { print $8 }'|sort -u|grep -v host>tempo_user.txt

for USER in `cat tempo_user.txt|awk -F"=" ' { print $2 } '`

  do

  export RESU=`cat pg.log*|grep ${database}|grep connection|grep ${USER}|sort -u|tail -1`

  echo "Last connexion of ${USER} on ${database} : ${RESU}"

  done

done
#
```